# How to create nested dictionary from two for loops?

Tags: python

Im using one regression analysis and the idea is to calculate the different scores based on min samples = i in range and b1 in range...

```
thisdict1  = {}

for i1 in range (1, 5):
    for b1 in range (1, 6):
        ransac2 = RANSACRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression(), min_samples=i1, max_trials=b1)
        ransac2.fit(X_test, y_test)
        m2 = ransac2.score(X_test, y_test)
        thisdict1.update({i1:{b1:m2}}) 

print(thisdict1)
```

The result is:

```
{1: {5: 0.9830502958579881}, 2: {5: 0.9848508230452674}, 3: {5: 0.9848508230452674}, 4: {5: 0.9848508230452674}}
```

Im trying to make a nested dictionary that contain not only the last b1 and m2 score but all of them. And of course all m2 score based on all i1 and b1 in their range. For example:

```
{1: {1: 0.969898, 2: 0.97854, 3: 0.986548, 4:0.989845, 5:0.9785488}, 2: {1: but m2 equals to i1 = 2 and b1 =1, m2 = i1(2), b1(2).. etc }, 3: {1: but m2 equals to i1 = 3 and b1 =1; m2 = i1 (3) and b1 (2) ...  }, 4: {...}}
```

Comment: What's a `RANSACRegressor`? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], which has tips like showing what you've already tried and making a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

`RANSACRegressor` is irrelevant to the problem. `m2` could just as easily be defined as `i1 * b1` and reproduce the same issue, namely that only the last `b1` value is kept in the inner dict.

The problem is that you're overwriting `thisdict1[i1]` every time. What you want to do instead is set `thisdict1[i1] = {}` in the outer loop, then add `b1` to that dict in the inner loop.

```
thisdict1 = {}

for i1 in range(2, 4):
    thisdict1[i1] = inner = {}
    for b1 in range(10, 12):
        m2 = i1 * b1
        inner[b1] = m2

print(thisdict1)
```

Output:

```
{2: {10: 20, 11: 22}, 3: {10: 30, 11: 33}}
```

(Here I'm using an alias `inner` to avoid writing the clunky `thisdict1[i1][b1]`.)

BTW, in general, calling `dict.update()` with a dict literal with one key is overcomplicated. The same thing can be more easily expressed with indexing. I.e., replace `d.update({k: v})` with `d[k] = v`.